# Write a list to csv file without looping in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of list of lists that I need to write to a csv file.

```
mylist = [['Siddharth','Bangalore','blah@gmail.com'],  
        ['Rahul','Bangalore','blah2@gmail.com'],.....and so on]
```

This list is usually some 20,000 to 40,000 long.
So, right now, the only way to write them to a csv file is to iterate over the list and write:

```
fileObj = open("/home/siddharth/sample.csv", "wb")
csv_file = csv.writer(fileObj)  
for item in mylist:  
    csv_file.writerow(item)
```

So, I just to wanted to know, is there a way to write such a list of lists to csv, without iterating over each item in the list, eg. like using `StringIO` etc.
Or, can anyone give some tip/hint, so that I can create my own implementation.

Comment: If you're looking to improve performance, then that should be your question. Don't assume that not looping is an automatic performance improvement. You can't eliminate the loop. Looping will happen somewhere, even if non-obvious. Attempts to eliminate the loop will likely result in the entire contents of the file being handled in memory at once, which is likely to be even less efficient.

Comment: Right! thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: run `python -mcProfile your_script.py` to find out which functions take the most time.

Comment: @MichaelMior - "the entire contents of the file being handled in memory at once, which is likely to be even less efficient" - where do you get that this is likely to be less efficient? Moving disk i/o to memory to reduce numbers of disk accesses is a common performance optimization. And I don't think 40,000 elements of 40-60 characters each will put much strain on most computer systems today.

Comment: Python already uses buffered I/O, so disk writes won't happen immediately. And since the goal is to write to file, doing more in memory before beginning the write is likely just to add more of a delay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [`writerows`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) method which will add all the rows in an iterable:

```
csv_file.writerows(the_list)
```

Whatever you do, there will always be a loop somewhere (either in your code or in the Python library implementation). There is no way around it as you need to look at each item in the list so that you can write them to the file.

In case you're worried about the performance of writing each line to the file separately: Python uses buffered I/O by default, so even if you write the list items one by one in a loop, they won't necessarily be written like that to the file. They will be written in chunks whenever the buffer fills up, which will have better performance. If needed, you can explicitly control the buffer size by using the `buffering` parameter of [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: Yeah, as i said, it also uses a for loop to iterate over the list. Which is eventually the same thing that I do.

Comment: @SiddharthSrivastava: There has to be a loop somewhere since you need to iterate over the list in order to get its contents.

Comment: yes right. Was just wondering, if something can be done. I know I sound weird when I say so, but maybe something can be done.

Comment: And, thanks for the information regarding, buffered I/O. I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: This seems to transpose my data - any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

```
csv_file.writerows(mylist)
```

(Note the `s` in [`writerows()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows))

Comment: No, if you see the source code for csvfile.writerows() , the you'll find that it also iterates over the list.
Just go through it.

Comment: @SiddharthSrivastava: Well, how else would it write it to the file? *Someone* has to do the iteration, so it might as well be Python.

Comment: except that It just moves the loop inside `csv` module. There is no way to write a 2d list as csv without looking at each item at some point (iterating over the list)

Comment: Yeah, I know that is the most obvious way. That is why I asked, if there is any special approach, or a workaround that. Like maybe using StringIO.

Comment: @Sebastian, yes you are right, I was just wondering, if we can figure out something :)

Comment: @SiddharthSrivastava: csv.writer can write to StringIO but what do you want to achieve by it?

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm mainly try to flush (I'm not sure if 'flush' is the write word to use here) this list of lists to StringIO, in such a way (though I need to find that 'way'), so that this 2d list gets written in one go, without looping.

Comment: @SiddharthSrivastava: What effect (visible outside your program) do you want to get? Is it performance (speed)? Is it atomicity (either all rows from the list are written to a file or none)?

Comment: @Sebastian, I'm mainly looking for performance improvement. Atomicity is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

These are all tuples of strings? Only 40,000 of them? Have you tried this?

```
with open('outputfile.csv','w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write('\n'.join(map(','.join, my_list)+'\n'))
```

You are *still* iterating over the list, but doing so using `map`, which is implemented in Python's C library.