# Python, write csv single row, multiple column

Tags: python, csv

Sorry for asking i have searched a lot but cant find what i need.

I need this list to be written to a csv file on one row(1) and each element from A to E

```
coluna_socio = ['bilhete', 'tipo', 'nome', 'idade', 'escalao']
outfile = open('socios_adeptos.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
for i in range(len(coluna_socio)):
    writer.writerow([coluna_socio[i]])
```

Ive tried almost everything and it always write on on column or just in on cell(A1)
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a list to csv file without looping in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054882/write-a-list-to-csv-file-without-looping-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string join method to insert a comma between all the elements of your list. Then write the resulting string to file. The `csv` module isn't necessary in this case.

For example ...

```
with open('socios_adeptos.csv', 'w') as out:
    out.write(','.join(coluna_socio))
```

Comment: That writes everything with a coma in the first cell A1..i need each item without comas and each on his own cell, like: A1 Bilhete B1 Tipo C1 Nome..

Comment: How are you reading the resulting file? You could replace `','` with any delimiter

Comment: I need it to be on a Excel worksheet, one row 5 columns and what i always got is one row one column

Comment: I'm not sure how your excel is configured, but you could try `out.write('\t'.join(coluna_socio))` which uses a tab as a delimiter. Otherwise, when you import into excel, try to set comma as delimiter

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `csv.writer.writerow` method with the list directly:

```
with open('socios_adeptos.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(coluna_socio)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could write it in one row with your code, as follows:

```
coluna_socio = ['bilhete', 'tipo', 'nome', 'idade', 'escalao']
outfile = open('socios_adeptos.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(coluna_socio)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Ive tried this, it writes on same row and same cell A1..not what i want..could this be a problem from my ms excel?