# How to write on each iteration to a csv file

Tags: python-3.x

How do i write to a csv file in each iteration one line.
I would like to have this kind of behaviour.

```
import time
import csv

path = 'C:/Blender_Scripts/test.csv'
for i in range(0,100):
    time.sleep(1)
    with open(path, 'a+', newline='') as Pt_file:
        Pt_writer = csv.writer(Pt_file)
        Pt_writer.writerow([i])
```

Is there a way to do this in a perfomance useful way?

Comment: yep. remove the `time.sleep(1)` from your code ...

Comment: and quit opening  the same file over and over and over and over again - open it wonce, write all

Comment: But without opening again and again it writes the whole list at once and not iteration by iteration.I need to read the file at the same time

Comment: you can take help from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054882/write-a-list-to-csv-file-without-looping-in-python